# Surface integral over an ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I am trying to determine the outward flux integral of the vector field $$F(x,y,z) = \frac {(x-y)i + (x+y)j + zk}{(x^2+y^2+4z^2)^{3/2}}$$
across the ellipsoid $x^2 + y^2 + 4z^2=4$.

Could I have a hint for this? I can't use the divergence theorem because of the singularity, so I am trying to evaluate it directly. I have replaced the denominator with 8 but I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: [ellipsoidal coordinates](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfocalEllipsoidalCoordinates.html) will be a great help here.

Comment: @K.defaoite which substitutions do I make?

Comment: Please do not delete your question just after receiving an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to write the answer, and disrespectful to future users who may have been interested in the answer.

Comment: @XanderHenderson k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parametrizing is unnecessary after a simplification. The integrand of the surface integral simplifies to

$$F(x,y,z) = \frac{(x-y,x+y,z)}{8}$$

by plugging in $x^2+y^2+4z^2=4$. This *is* a vector field divergence theorem applies to:

$$\nabla\cdot F = \frac{3}{8}$$

which means the integral evaluates to $\frac{3}{8}\operatorname{vol}(x^2+y^2+4z^2\leq 4) = 2\pi$